# Navigating to a new frame from code generated hyperlink in a richtextblock

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on a Wikipedia app and I would like to click a hyperlink and have reload the frame with the content of the page clicked. I get an *"An object reference is required for a non-static field"* compiler error when I try to use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(page))`in my click event handler.

I am further confused because the navigation succeeds if I create a button in XAML and pass the same code into the click event handler.

This is the method click event handler I'm using for the hyperlinks:

```
private static async void Hyperlink_Click(Hyperlink sender, HyperlinkClickEventArgs args)
{
    //Get hyperlink text to query API
    string hyperLinktext = (sender?.Inlines[0] as Run)?.Text

    //Parse content and store in object
    WikiContent_Rootobject rootobj = await 
    GetPageContentFromHyperlink(hyperlinktext)

    //Attempt to navigate to 'ContentPage' and send rootobj
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContentPage), rootobj)
}
```

So my question is: Why doesn't this method of navigation work in this scenario?

Thanks for the help!

[image: Picture for clarification of app layout]

[image: Picture of methods I'm using]

Comment: You could not invoke instance method in the static method. Could you told me why do you make  static event handler? In my side, the hyperlink click event is instance method.

Comment: I made it as a static event because that's how visual studio created it when I hit tab. I have played around with the event handler by removing the static, then creating a new instance of my page and invoking the event handler through the instance. In this scenario the program will run, but I run into an _Object reference not set to an instance of an object_ exception when I click it. [Screenshot of my non-static implementation and the error](https://imgur.com/a/nJtDL1i)

Comment: I have seen your screen short. I found you add `contentpg.Hyperlink_Click` event handler to `Hyperlink` `Click` event and in the second screen  short that the `Hyperlink_Click` method is private. I don't know how do you get it from contentpg instance?

Comment: `Hyperlink_Click` is defined on `ContentPage.xaml.cs` within `public sealed partial class ContentPage : Page`. I figured that if I cannot use a static method, that I would need to create a new instance of this class in order to access the `Hyperlink_Click` event handler. I have tried setting `Hyperlink_Click` to public, but I still get the same _Object reference not set to an instance of an object_ exception.

Comment: Please share mini code sample. Otherwise, we hardly to give an answer based on incomplete information.